# Subset algorithm between two lists -- why is the worst case when len(L1) = len(L2)?

Tags: python, asymptotic-complexity

I have an algorithm that determines whether a list L1 is a subset of a list L2 (i.e. whether all elements in L1 are in L2):

```
def isSubset(L1, L2):
    for e1 in L1:
        matched = False
        for e2 in L2:
            if e1 == e2:
                matched = True
                break
        if not matched:
            return False
    return True
```

In the notes of my course, it says that "the worst case occurs when len(L1) = len(L2)", but why is this?

My reasoning is: for a given L1 and L2, the worst case occurs when L1 is indeed a subset of L2 (in which case, for every L1, we have to go through every element in L2 to verify this).

If this is the case (i.e. L1 is a subset of L2), then it's going to take longer to verify that L1 is a member of, say, [1,7,2,3,5,8,9,20], than it is to verify that it's a member of, say, [2,5,3].

What is wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: stupid remark: why not using `set`s for this (and method `issubset()`)? linear search will always be much slower.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That's the example that I've been given.

Comment: As Jean noted, this isn't the best approach, but I think your logic is broadly correct. When you `return False` you short-circuit, but not when you `return True`

Comment: By the way, you wrote `for el in L1`, while I guess you meant `for e1 in L1`

Comment: For a given `L2`, worst case is when `L1` is equal to `L2`. For a given `L1`, there's no boundary on the worst `L2` : it could be `L1` with an infinity of elements added.

Comment: @EricDuminil Ah. So that's what the lecturer meant when he said that the worst case is when `L1` is equal to `L2`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when `L1` is equal to `L2`, all the elements of `L1` have to be checked against `L2`.

On the other hand, if `L1` is not equal to `L2`, either it is a subset of it, or it is not.

If it is, fewer checks will be necessary, since there will be fewer elements in `L1` than if `L1` was as long as `L2`.

Else, as soon as an element not belonging to `L2` is discovered in `L1`, it is certain that `L1` cannot be a subset of `L2`.

On the other hand, if `len(L1) == len(L2)` but the first element of `L1` is not in `L2`, the execution will require only one loop over `L2`.

Therefore, worst case => `len(L1) == len(L2)`, but the converse is not true.